# What is meant by "short lived" in the duration of a planetary nebula?

Tags: nebula

In this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebula#Planetary_nebulae), it describes planetary nebula as "short-lived," but I'm not sure in relation to what?  This could mean billions of years in some contexts.

**How long is short-lived?**

Bonus if there are any useful rules of thumb in astronomy terms for future uses (how stars timelines are described, versus galaxies, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

In the case of planetary nebulae we are talking of ~10,000 years (follow the link to the main article on [Planetary Nebulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_nebula#Lifetime)).

In general a short lifetime for a phenomena means a time short compared to the total life of the entity it is related to. It is an informal term and does not have a fixed maximum value, but 10,000 years is a short time on most astronomical scales.